# Plotting a solution of DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to plot a solution of a differential equation system. This is what I have:

```
sol = DSolve[{X[t] == a + b Y[t], Y'[t] == c + d Z[t], Z[t] == Exp[t]}, {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, t]
```

Parameter values are given, say:

```
a = 10
b = 0.7
c = 4
d = 2.4
```

Then, I have the `Plot` code as:

```
Plot[Evaluate[X[t], Y[t], Z[t] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1}], {t, 0, 50}]
```

And I am failing to obtain a correct result. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing a parenthesis. This works:

Plot[Evaluate[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]} /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1}], {t, 0, 50}]

If you want a 3D plot you should write:

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]} /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1}], {t, 0, 50}]

Hope this helps